# How to get a File from an OutputStream to retrieve uploaded file

Tags: java, vaadin7

After receiving the uploaded file i want to return a File representing the uploaded file i overrode the receiveUpload methode:

```
 /**
  * Invoked when a new upload arrives.
  * 
 * @param filename
 *            the desired filename of the upload, usually as specified
 *            by the client.
 * @param mimeType
 *            the MIME type of the uploaded file.
 * @return Stream to which the uploaded file should be written.
 */

 public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType);`
```

So What is the best way to return a `new File` object.

Comment: pls show the code you tried not just signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on what you want to do. The method `receiveUpload()` is part of the [`Receiver`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Upload.Receiver.html) interface. You need to provide an `outputStream` that Vaadin can use to write the uploaded data to.

You might not always want to write to a file. Maybe you want to write to a database or just to a byte array in order to further process the data.

Assuming you want to write to a file, you just have to create a file on disk and return the `FileOutputStream` to this file.

To create a temporary file, you can use this:

```
    File file = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".tmp");
    return new FileOutputStream(file);
```

But if you want to write to a specific location, you can directly provide the fill file path, e.g.:

```
    File file = new File("/path/to/my/file/storage/" + filename);
    return new FileOutputStream(file);
```

For more information have a look at the [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.upload.html).